# Class Object, Incorporating a separate class as a field

Tags: c#, class

I have two classes but I need to link `CheckingAccount.cs` in `Customer.cs`. The professor for my class mentioned `Has A` but I'm not entirely sure what he was referring to. Here is my class files. They need to have a constructor and I believe I have that part right. I need to have a checking account field w/in the `Customer.cs` class, but I'm not sure how to link them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Customer.CS

```
class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    //Need to have a field here with the Checking Account Object.

    public Customer(string _customerName)
    {
        CustomerName = _customerName;
    }
}
```

## CheckingAccount.CS

```
class CheckingAccount
{
    public decimal AccountBalance {get; set;}
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public CheckingAccount(decimal _accountBalance, int _accountNumber)
    {
        AccountBalance = _accountBalance;
        AccountNumber = _accountNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Inheritance (IS-A) vs. Composition (HAS-A) Relationship](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php)

Comment: You could just add a `CheckingAccount` property to the `Customer class`, the same way as you added the `string CustomerName` property (and typically you don't need to repeat the class name as part of the property name - the property is normally just called `"Name"`). The downside of adding a single property called `CheckingAccount` is that it assumes they only have one. In a one-to-many relationship between classes like this, the customer would have a `public List<CheckingAccount> CheckingAccounts { get; set; }` so they could have more than one.

Comment: @RufusL so you mean to say I should add `(string _customerName, CheckingAccount checkingAccount)` and that's it?

Comment: That would be it for the constructor, but you'd also need to create the class *property*( to assign from the constructor. Otherwise there's no way to access it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with files. It has to do with types and objects. Classes are types. Therefore, you must have a property of `CheckingAccount` type in class `Customer` and pass it a `CheckingAccount` object in the constructor:

```
class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public CheckingAccount Account { get; set; }

    public Customer(string customerName, CheckingAccount account)
    {
        CustomerName = customerName;
        Account = account;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a customer like this:

```
var account = new CheckingAccount(100m, 123); // Create CheckingAccount object.
var customer = new Customer("xTwisteDx", account);
```

If the account doesn't change during the lifetime of the customer object, you can also make the property read-only.

```
public CheckingAccount Account { get; }
```

Such a property can only be initialized in the constructor or by using an initializer as in:

```
public CheckingAccount Account { get; } = new CheckingAccount(0m, 0);
```

The same is true for the `CustomerName`.

Comment: Aha! So essentially I'm creating a new `CheckingAccount` type named `Account` which is an object defined in `CheckingAccount.cs`.Makes sense, I figured it was something simple, still trying to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: The *.cs files are not important. You could even declare both classes in the same file (not a good idea, but you could). What you are doing is to declare a **property** of type `CheckingAccount` named `Account`. This is done at design time. The **object** is created at runtime when `new CheckingAccount(100m, 123)` is executed and is first assigned to a variable. This variable contains a reference to the account object. This reference is then passed to the constructor in `new Customer("xTwisteDx", account)`. In the constructor this reference is then assigned to the property.